# Why does my application kept crashing after i clicked sign in?

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-authentication

My problem is when I run the code and from there, I click on the sign-in button and the app just crashes and when I run debugger they will skip the line that was supposed to be executed. I tried the same code on different PC's, and the problem is still the same where they didn't read a line where it's supposed to be executed. what I want to say basically, is if I click the sign-in button without inputting words in the field which is (email) it should be given a statement saying that " Please input your email ". this also happens with the password field.

this my button click listener:

```
   @Override
public void onClick(View view) {
    if(view == buttonSignin){
            userLogin();
    }
}
```

Method userLogin:

```
     private void userLogin() {
    String email = etEmail.getText().toString().trim();
    String password = etPassword.getText().toString().trim();

    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

    progressDialog.setMessage("Login Please wait...");
    progressDialog.show();

    firebaseAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,password)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    progressDialog.dismiss();

                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        finish();
                        userVerified();
                    } else {

                        String errorCode = ((FirebaseAuthException) task.getException()).getErrorCode();

                        switch (errorCode) {

                            case "ERROR_INVALID_EMAIL":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is badly formatted.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                etEmail.setError("The email address is badly formatted.");
                                etEmail.requestFocus();
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_WRONG_PASSWORD":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The password is invalid ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                etPassword.setError("password is incorrect ");
                                etPassword.requestFocus();
                                etPassword.setText("");
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_USER_MISMATCH":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The supplied credentials do not correspond to the previously signed in user.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_REQUIRES_RECENT_LOGIN":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "This operation is sensitive and requires recent authentication. Log in again before retrying this request.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_ACCOUNT_EXISTS_WITH_DIFFERENT_CREDENTIAL":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "An account already exists with the same email address but different sign-in credentials. Sign in using a provider associated with this email address.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;

                            case "ERROR_EMAIL_ALREADY_IN_USE":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "The email address is already in use by another account.   ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                etEmail.setError("The email address is already in use by another account.");
                                etEmail.requestFocus();
                                break;
                            case "ERROR_USER_NOT_FOUND":
                                Toast.makeText(Signin.this, "Your account not registered", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

Code skip on the empty field:

```
 if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

I got this when i run debugger:

[image]

does this happen because there are many errors in my looper.java?

[image]

How do I solve it?

Comment: Add stack trace of crash

Comment: Please add crash stack trace

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to return in case of empty `email` or `password`

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
    //email is empty
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return;
}
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
    //password is empty
    Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    return;
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot bro just realized.

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
if(TextUtils.isEmpty(email)){
        //email is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter email", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    }
    if(TextUtils.isEmpty(password)){
        //password is empty
        Toast.makeText(this, "Please enter password", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

After check there is nothing happening with this. You only get the info about empty fields (Toasts), but code is still executing. So you try to login with empty fields.